Playwright cucumberjs allure report getting an error
I have integrated playwright with cucumber javascript with allure   reporting. I    have looked at the allure official documentation for allure   with cucumberjs. I have taken this
config.js  

module.exports = {
parallel: 4,
format: ["./configs/reporter.js"],
};

reporter.js     


const { AllureRuntime } = require("allure-js-commons");
const { CucumberJSAllureFormatter } = require("allure-cucumberjs");

module.exports = class extends CucumberJSAllureFormatter {
constructor(options) {
super(options, new AllureRuntime({ resultsDir: "./allure-results" }), {});
}
};    

when I run the test cases  I am getting an error
Error: Failed to import formatter ./configs/reporter.js

and
[cause]:Type Error: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
Could anyone help me on this?
